# How to calculate $A^n$ $\forall n\in \mathbb N$ when having its diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let be $A$
>
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & -1\\ -1 & 3 & -1\\ -1 & 1 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> and $f\in L(\mathbb R^3)$ cannonically associated to $A$.
>
> Having the diagonal matrix 
>   $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> **How to calculate $A^n$ $\forall n\in \mathbb N$?**

An advice was to use

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & -1\\ -1 & 2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

and its revert to use the formula $A^n=PB^nP^{-1}$ but I don't understand why and where such a $P$ comes from...

Comment: If $A=PBP^{-1}$, $A^2=PBP^{-1}PBP^{-1}=PB^2P^{-1}$, etc.

Comment: @frank000 Thank you! And what is $P$?

Comment: The matrix you wrote in your question. That is usually the "change of basis" matrix in order to make $B$ diagonal.

Comment: @frank000 Understood!

Answer (score 0):

You can proof that: $A = PBP^{-1} \to A^n = P B^n P^{-1}$ and

$$ B^= \begin{pmatrix}
1^n & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2^n & 0 \\ 0&0&2^n
\end{pmatrix}$$